# How can i find what time a search on chrome was done

Tags: search, history, time

When looking at your chrome history search, is there a way to see the time that the original site was searched?

Comment: What do you mean by original site? I can see time and website url also in in chrome's history. Please explain your query
Do you want to see the time when you visited website first time?

Comment: yes, i would like to see the actual time when website was visited.

Answer (score 11):

This functionality is built-into Chrome. Just hover your mouse over an entry, and the time stamp appears.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: For those looking for a more 'programmatic' way to access this data: the hover tooltip data is from the `title` attribute of the element in the page. See https://superuser.com/a/1429938/382131 to get it.

Answer (score 4):

Google chrome's history does not show time for past days. It shows time only for present day. If you have logged-in your gmail account with chrome then you can look at history by date/time specifically through this url www.google.com/history

Edited: I searched on google there are some softwares that can track chrome history by time also.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it directly answers the question and doesn't require third party or OS-specific software.

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way:

1. Go to chrome history (ctrl+H)
2. Right click on the date of the desired entry and select 'inspect'
3. The full timestamp with the user timezone is displayed inside *title* field

Answer (score 3):

This is overkill, but:

1. Find the file /AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/History
2. Copy this file to a Linux machine and run this command:

   sqlite3 History "select datetime(visit_time/1000000-11644473600,'unixepoch') as datetime, urls.url || '
   ' from visits join urls on urls.id = visits.url;" > history.html
3. Open the newly created history.html file. It will have a list of your entire browsing history along with the date and time that you visited each page.

Answer (score 2):

use [ChromeHistoryView v1.35 
Copyright (c) 2011 - 2018 Nir Sofer](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_history_view.html)

works great

> ### Description
>
> ChromeHistoryView is a small utility that reads the history data file of Google Chrome Web browser, and displays the list
>   of all visited Web pages in the last days. For each visited Web page,
>   the following information is displayed: URL, Title, Visit Date/**Time**,
>   Number of visits, number of times that the user typed this address
>   (Typed Count), Referrer, and Visit ID.
>
> ### Using ChromeHistoryView
>
> ChromeHistoryView doesn't require any installation process or
>   additional DLL files. In order ti start using it, simply copy the
>   executable file (ChromeHistoryView.exe) to any folder you like, and
>   run it.

PS:- you can't see history with the time in google by default

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Thank you for you contribution, but whilst this may potentially answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential information here, and provide the link for reference. Please **edit your answer** to include that information. Thanks :)

Comment: @bertieb That _is_ the essential information. It's not formatted very nicely but it's a good answer overall. What information would you prefer was included?

Comment: The bits in bold from [how to recommend software in answers](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers), for example.

Answer (score 0):

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/when-timestamps-for-googl/dgafcidlgmbcehokgdeghmfnbpbfhihh

here's an extension (called "When?") for Chrome that puts time stamps next to any link that you've opened in Google. it works retroactively so it will timestamp any visited link in your browsing history.

Answer (score 0):

If you load Chrome for iOS, it shows the time stamps (to the minute), so if your history is synched, you can view the same history on an iPad or iPhone to see the time stamp.

Answer (score 0):

Answering because I just had this question and found the answers seemed overly complex.

When you view the history page any of `Menu > History > History`, or as <kbd>CTRL></kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd>, or as `chrome://history/`, the display shows the time (`HH:mm`) and url, grouped by day.
If you perform a search, then the results show the date (`mmm, dd, yyyy`) and the url.

In either form, hovering over the date or time shows the actual timestamp.
This is presented in your local time. (The GMT threw me until I realized it meant "GMT - 4 hours".)

Ex:

```
Mon Oct 21, 2019 08:08:03 GMT -0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

PS: This is with Chrome 77.0.3865.120 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

Google chrome's history doesn't show time for past days. It shows time just for present day. In the event that you have signed in your gmail account with chrome, at that point you can see history by date/time explicitly through this url www.google.com/history

Comment: Someone else said this already